# How to move an animated line in html 5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this animated line that I am building using HTML5 Canvas class. I am trying to move the line to the left when I hit up left button. I am still new to web development and just started messing around with HTML and JS. Therefore, I request you to help me out. Please explain in detail so I can learn what I am doing wrong! Thanks! I have this following code

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <button type="button" id="startButton">Start</button>
    <button type="button" id="left">Left</button>
        <button type="button" id="left">Right</button>

    <script>
 (function(){

    function init(){

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var direction=0;
canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 200;

var points = [],
    currentPoint = 20000,
    nextTime = new Date().getTime()+500,
    pace = 200;
   var startingx=25,startingy=0;
// make some points
for (var i = 0; i < canvas.height ; i++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < canvas.width ; k++){
            points.push({
                    x: i ,
                    y: k
        });
    }
}
        function draw(){

    if(new Date().getTime() > nextTime){
        nextTime = new Date().getTime() + pace;

        currentPoint++;

    }
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(points[20000].x, points[20000].y);
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0000';
       for (var p = 20000, plen = currentPoint; p < plen; p++) {
       if(direction==0)
        {ctx.lineTo(points[p].x, points[p].y);ctx.stroke();}
    else if(direction==1)
        {ctx.lineTo(points[p+200].x, points[p+200].y);ctx.stroke();}
    else if(direction==2)
        {ctx.lineTo(points[p-2].x, points[p-2].y);ctx.stroke();}
    else if(direction==3)
        {ctx.lineTo(points[p-200].x, points[p-200].y);
        ctx.stroke();}


    }
            cancelMe = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        }


        function startAnimation(event){
            if(this.textContent === "Start"){
                requestAnimationFrame(draw);
                this.textContent = 'Pause';
            }
            else{
                cancelAnimationFrame(cancelMe);
                this.textContent = 'Start';

            }

        }
        function leftTurn(event){
            direction++;
            if(direction>3)
            {
                direction=0;
            }

        }
        function rightTurn(event){
            direction--;
            if(direction<0)
            {
                direction=3;
            }

        }
        var startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');
        startButton.addEventListener('click',startAnimation,false);
        var leftButton = document.getElementById('left');
        var rightButton = document.getElementById('right');
        leftButton.addEventListener('click',leftTurn,false);
        rightButton.addEventListener('click',rightTurn,false);

    }

//invoke function init once document is fully loaded
    window.addEventListener('load',init,false);

}()); //self invoking function

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your for loop goes from 20000 to 20000. You forgot to call ctx.beginPath before drawing your path.

Comment: But, I am incrementing currentpoint each time it executes the loop so loop only runs one time per instance! can you post an answer regarding the loop and usage of begin path ?

Comment: I'm on my phone and may have misread your code, sorry. But what you do change in your loop is plen. This means that you'll always start at p [20000] and end at p[plen]. Is there such a point? Do you have an error in the console? And for beginPath, it should be called at least once per stroke, otherwise all previous drawings will be stroked at each iteration.

Comment: I am already calling ctx.beginPath(); here after clearRect method. Additionally, I tried utilising your looping suggestions. I found that looping without plen just prints a big chunk of line as soon as I hit start. Hence, It does not animate properly. Thanks much! Please help me out!

Comment: `points.length` should be equal to 39999, so your loop starts at `points[20000]` and then draws each `points[20000+n]` until `n+20000 === currentPoint`. When currentPoint will be greater than 39999, your code will crash. Until then, you'll add `points[n]` every time to your whole path. And since you are calling `ctx.stroke()` at each iteration, at third iteration, you 'll have drawn 3 times `points[n]`, 2 times points[n+1]` and one time `points[n+2]`. To avoid it, either call `ctx.stroke()` at the end of your loop, or call `ctx.beginPath` at each iteration (this would require a `moveTo` too.

Comment: If I do that then the output is a thick chunk of line printed all at once it neither animates itself nor it goes point by point. Therefore, I am unable to implement left and right functionality!